# Azure CLI equivalent of Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I need to associate a custom claims mapping policy with an application and am not seeing an equivalent to PowerShell's Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy in the documentation. Am I missing it?

Answer (score 0):

Based off our [az ad sp CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest) and [az policy assignment identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/assignment/identity?view=azure-cli-latest) documentation, I wasn't able to find an equivalent command within CLI to the [Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadserviceprincipalpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) PowerShell command.

If you'd like this to be added to the list of CLI commands, I'd recommend creating a feature request using our new [User Voice forum](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community) so our engineering team can take a look at implementing this.

Additional Link:
[az ad app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest)

Thank you for your time and patience throughout this issue.